# Canvas zindex issue

Tags: canvas, z-index

I am using fabric js api. There are two canvas on the page. If I display both of them, then all is good. But, I want only one to display at a time. So, I am using absolute position so that the display region is same. Issue I am facing is that, when the first canvas has been loaded, and I load the second canvas, somehow the z-index of first loaded canvas is higher. Because, I am not able to select the elements placed on the second canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the CSS `z-index` value of the canvases in a few different ways, either by inline-styles in the HTML-tags or via a stylesheet - but CSS `z-index` values only work on elements with a `position` value and where that value is not set to `static`.

When layering HTML page elements directly on top of each other it is sometimes useful to places them inside a container element, for example...

```
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Bearing in mind that child elements inherit `z-index` values from their parents, therefore they require an explicit declaration, this arrangement can be style with stylesheet entries like so...

```
#canvas-container {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
/* canvas position */
#canvas1, #canvas2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
/* canvas z-index */
#canvas1 {
    z-index:200;
}
#canvas2 {
    z-index:300;
}
```

This will place `#canvas1` beneath `#canvas2` as overlapping elements with lower `z-index` values are arranged beneath elements with higher values.

The CSS width and height values of all three elements can also be set to the same values to help maintain page layout...

```
#canvas-container, #canvas1, #canvas2 {
    width:???px;
    height:???px;
}
```

Similar CSS properties and values can be added to the HTML-tags directly with [the html `style` attribute](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/inline), or [added dynamically via JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml).

**See Also**: [MDN article on CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index).